# statistics functions not working!! python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, statistics, python-import

Every time U try to import statistics in VS and try to use it's functions like `.mean()`, `.mode()` etc, I get this error please help!

```
import statistics

grades = {85, 93, 45, 89, 85}
mode = statistics.mode(grades)
print(mode)
```

results:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
partially initialized module 'statistics' has no attribute 'mode' (most likely due to a circular import)
  File "C:\Users\Rashad\Desktop\Tools\Programming Stuff\Python\statistics.py", line 4, in <module>
    mode = statistics.mode(grades)
  File "C:\Users\Rashad\Desktop\Tools\Programming Stuff\Python\statistics.py", line 1, in <module>
    import statistics
```

Comment: Your file is named statistics.py. Don't name it the same thing as the python builtin module

Comment: is your python script named statistics.py?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error, because your script have the same name as the module you are trying to import:

`statistics.py` and `statistics`

Python uses [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#path-entry-finders) to identify which module to import.

The first entry in `sys.path` is empty string which denotes the current directory, and in this case it will import the module call `statistics` from current directory (which is not a standard module you're expecting) and therefore getting the aforementioned error.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you explained **why** you can't do this (python module resolution precedence)

Comment: @m0nhawk thanks it worked plus it worked without renaming the file other than statistics.py i put this at the first line : from Lib import statistics